# Storing a hash of hashes in Redis

Tags: ruby, redis, hash-of-hashes

What's the best way to store an hash in Redis which looks like this:

```
id1->{key1->value1, key2->value2, key3->value3….} , id3->{key1->value1, key2->value2, key3->value3….} ….
```

where `key1, key2, key3`... is two-letters code of language (en, es, etc), but some of they keys can have different set of languages, and a key can have about 30 different languages.

Comment: I would suggest having each `id` as a key for a [hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash)

Comment: @UriAgassi, the keys will repeat. Which one of the ways do you suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you show a more concrete example?

Comment: @UriAgassi, how to store the hash shown above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This fits just right in Redis [HASH](http://redis.io/topics/data-types/#hashes), you can use [HMSET](http://redis.io/commands/hmset) to add all fields to each hash:

```
HMSET id1 key1 value1 key2 value2 ...
HMSET id2 key1 value1 key2 value2 ...
HMSET id3 key1 value1 key2 value2 ...
...
```

You might want to [SADD](http://redis.io/commands/sadd) all HASHs key names into a [SET](http://redis.io/topics/data-types/#sets) to be able to get all of their names:

```
SADD ids id1 id2 id3 ...
```